# On a Heroku app, how to install Python pip dependencies in a Ruby server?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a simple Sinatra server which is deploying correctly using the Ruby buildpack.

Now I need to install a pip dependency which will be called by the Ruby code.

I followed the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

I run:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
```

Then when I deploy with `git push heroku master`, I see this error:

> remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
>
> remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

My Procfile is as follows - it launches rack which in turn runs a sinatra server

```
# Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

I haven't yet written the code to install the pip dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to run

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

Even though when I run this, it says

> Error: The buildpack heroku/ruby is already set on your app.

it still prevents the error i showed in my question, upon deploy.

And when I move requirements.txt to the root of my project, I do see that pip and the dependencies get installed. When I connect with `heroku run bash` I can succesfully run my Python script.